# ASP.NET Web API Handles Two Integers Differently

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json-deserialization

I have a model in my Web API project that accepts two integers:

```
public int ParentId { get; set; }
public int ChildId { get; set; }
```

While testing the API, I tested sending crazy big numbers (like you do) in the JSON message:

```
{
    ParentId: 333333333333333333333333333333333333333,
    ChildId: 1
}
```

In the above case, the `ParentId` becomes `0`. Happy days.

In the following case, where the `ChildId` is passed with the exact same crazy big number, the whole model ends up `null`.

```
{
    ParentId: 1,
    ChildId: 333333333333333333333333333333333333333
}
```

Why does this not simply cause `ChildId` to become `0` as the `ParentId` did?

Comment: Interesting, looks like a bug to me. This only happens if the "erroneous" value is the last parameter in the json data. For example, if you add another integer with a normal value and supply it after ChildId, then the whole model is fine again.

Comment: Ah yes - if I reorder, the problem changes to `if the last element has a crazy big number` - good suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this issue by appending a comma. Neat`</sarcasm>`.

```
{
    ParentId: 2,
    ChildId: 333333333333333333333333333333333333333,
}
```

So it does indeed look like a deserializer bug as noted by @djikay in the comments above.

**Update**: The issue has been fixed: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/315

Comment: If you add the XML serialiser: `var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter; xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;` to your project, then that will not accept any bad value and will always result in a `null` model. It seems a "feature" with the default json serialiser.

Comment: Yes - we found the XML was always null no matter what - the JSON seems more permissive. This is an edge case so I don't think we're actually going to change any code to fix it - but we'll handle the possible outcomes.

Comment: It might be worth a note on Codeplex, where the various MS developers roam (although they are present here too). It does look like a genuine bug; I can't see why this would be intended behaviour for json only.